# C++ Implementation of a Binary Heap

Tags: c++, data-structures, heap, binary-tree

I need a min-heap implemented as a binary tree. Really fast access to the minimum node and insertion sort.

Is there a good implementation in stl or boost that anyone can point me too?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think [std::priority_queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

See the Standard C++ algorithm [make_heap](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/make_heap.html)().

Answer (score -1):

The STL doesn't have a concept of (binary) trees, but there are methods that facilitate in maintaining heap properties in a dataset, such as std::make_heap, std::sort_heap, std::push_heap et cetera.